# Discord.JS | TypeError: Cannot read property 'run' of null

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I keep getting the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'run' of null" when trying to run this code. Everything else in the program runs fine until it reaches the sql.run part.

(Note: there is other code in the program that handles all of the Discord.js part of things, only the part that is causing an issue is here)

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const sql = require("sqlite");
sql.open("./warnings.sqlite", {Promise});

   sql.get(`SELECT * FROM warnings WHERE userId ="${message.author.id}"`).then(row => {
    if (!row) {
        sql.run("INSERT INTO warnings (userId, level) VALUES (?, ?)", [message.author.id, 1]);
      console.log(row.level);
    } else {
        sql.run(`UPDATE warnings SET level = ${row.level + 1} WHERE userId = ${message.author.id}`);
      console.log(row.level);
    }
  }).catch(() => {
    sql.run("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS warnings (userId TEXT, level INTEGER)").then(() => {
        sql.run("INSERT INTO warnings (userId, level) VALUES (?, ?)", [message.author.id, 1]);
      });
  });
```

Comment: Try changing your `sql.open` line to return a handle, so say: `const db = sql.open("./warnings.sqlite", { Promise });`, and then using `db` instead of `sql` for your `get`/`run` calls.

Comment: @BrandonAnzaldi just tried that, got `TypeError: db.get is not a function`

Comment: Ah, my apologies. You need to wait for the db connection promise to return first, either with `async/await`, or putting the code inside of the db connection's `then` block. See the example on the NPM page https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite#how-to-use

Comment: @BrandonAnzaldi Awesome, thank you! That worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turning my comment into a full-fledged answer:

You're not returning a database driver to use, and instead are using it on the SQLite module itself. Try returning a connection handle, and using that for your queries. You'll have to wait for the database connection promise to resolve first, so assuming you have support for async/await, you can do something like this:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const sql = require("sqlite");
const dbProm = sql.open("./warnings.sqlite", {Promise});
const db = await dbProm;

   db.get(`SELECT * FROM warnings WHERE userId ="${message.author.id}"`).then(row => {
    if (!row) {
        db.run("INSERT INTO warnings (userId, level) VALUES (?, ?)", [message.author.id, 1]);
      console.log(row.level);
    } else {
        db.run(`UPDATE warnings SET level = ${row.level + 1} WHERE userId = ${message.author.id}`);
      console.log(row.level);
    }
  }).catch(() => {
    db.run("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS warnings (userId TEXT, level INTEGER)").then(() => {
        db.run("INSERT INTO warnings (userId, level) VALUES (?, ?)", [message.author.id, 1]);
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I remember using this a while back.

I went into my old code and all of it is the same except for the {Promise} where you open the database. Try removing that seeing as you do not use promises and it isn't [better-]sqlite3

```
sql.open("./warnings.sqlite")
```

Comment: There are promises in their code sample. The sqlite wrapper on NPM does provide promise support.

Comment: Sorry, I must not have made myself clear of what I meant. I used to, and still do, code Discord bots. I have old code that is about the same of what he is doing, with everything (pseudo of course) the same except for the fact of the {Promise}. Mine is old code so I can see if this may be outdated.